# How to Validate Receiver Paypal Email before Payout , Is their Any API?

Tags: api, validation, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payout

I am sending payment to user of my application but want to validate that Is Paypal account is exist on this email or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know if there is a PayPal account attached to an email address prior to a payment is to use [Connect with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/) to have the user log in with their account, and validate the response.

Otherwise, if you send a payment to an email address that has no account, they will receive a notification that there is money waiting and it will be auto-refunded after 30 days (with a reminder) if they do not claim it by creating an account or adding that email to an existing account.